# Is there a way to use a generic hostname that will work in both Docker and localhost?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, hostname

I’m on Mac OS Big Sur and running the following Docker versions

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
$ docker-compose -v
Docker Compose version v2.2.3
```

I’m running a Rails 6 app, whose database is configured like so

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: host.docker.internal
  database: cfs
  pool: 5
  username: myuser
  password: bypass
```

I have to use “host.docker.internal” so that the Rails app can access the Docker db when running inside of Docker, set up in my docker-compose.yml like so

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/provision/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: bypass
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
    …
  web:
    #restart: always
    build: ./my-project
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    expose:
      - '3000'
    command: foreman start
    volumes:
    - ./my-project/:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

However if I run the app locally without Docker, I have to change my config files to remove “host.docker.internal” and use “127.0.0.1” instead (or localhost).

Is there a way I can set things up so that I have a single database config file that works in both Docker and without Docker such that I don’t have to change the host around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use ERB markup in the `database.yml` file](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/configuring.html#configuring-a-database), which lets you use an environment variable here.  In general I'd suggest making default values for things be whatever default will work in a plain non-Docker development environment.

```yaml
# config/database.yml
development:
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
```

If you're running this in a setup where the database hostname isn't `localhost` – it's in a sibling container, or you're using a cloud-hosted database like Amazon RDS – you can set that environment variable.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    et: cetera
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: db  # <-- will be read in database.yml
```